# Find associated model of all objects in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

Using Rails 4, I have the following:

```
class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cars, dependent: :destroy
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :drivers
end
```

I have a join table `cars_drivers` with `car_id` and `patient_id`.

I want to find drivers who are 30 years old and above (`driver.age > 30`), drives a Honda (`car.brand = "Honda"`), and sum the number of drivers found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this:

```
@drivers =
  Driver.
    joins(:cars).
    where(cars_drivers: {
      driver_id: Driver.where('age > 30'),
      complication_id: Car.find_by_model("Honda").id
    }).
    size
```

Answer (score 0):

In a raw SQL fashion:

```
sql = "
SELECT
SUM (driver), age, brand 
FROM cars_drivers 
JOIN cars, drivers 
ON cars_drivers.car_id = cars.id
ON cars_drivers.driver_id = drivers.id    
where 
age > 30
and brand = "Honda"
"

records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should count the cars:

```ruby
Car.where(brand: BRAND).includes(:drivers).where('drivers.age > ?', AGE).count
```

This should count the drivers:

```ruby
Driver.where('age > ?', AGE).includes(:cars).where('cars.brand = ?', BRAND).count
```

I do recommend **not** using `has_and_belongs_to_many`, it seems like you have a lot of logic between the `Driver` and `Car` but with this setup you cannot have **validations**, **callbacks** or extra fields.

I would create a join model called `CarDriver` or if there is something even more describing like `Job` or `Delivery` and save them in their own table. Here is an [article](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/) on the subject.